# Integral Constant Increasing with Equation Output

Tags: integration, constants

I am working on an analytical solution for a numerical model, I have integrated the formula

**dT2/dt = F*Cp*(T1-T2)/M2*Cp**

**Where**

*T1 = Temperature in First Reactor*

*T2 = Temperature in Second Reactor*

*F = Feed Rate into Reactor 2*

*Cp = Specific Heat Capacity*

*M2 = Mass in Reactor 2*

I have integrated the equation to obtain

**T2 = T1 - k*exp(-Ft/M2)**

Where

*k = constant*

*t = time*

My initial conditions are

**at t = 0**

**T1 = 30**

**T2 = 20**

So from this I obtain

**20 = 30 - k*exp(0)**

**Therefore k = 10**

And

**T2 = T1 - 10*exp(-Ft/M2)**

However when I use this equation to compare my calculated T2 values to known T2 values from the numerical model, the calculated values are not within a range of negligible difference as desired.
I checked my equation for k using other known values of T2 and T1 and each time the value returned is different from the initially calculated value of 10.

For Example

**at t = 600**

**T1= 36.3**

**T2 = 28.9**

**k = 20.1**

Is someone able to please give me a reason for why this may be happening?

Comment: Why do you have $C_p$ multiplied into both the numerator and denominator of your fraction without cancelling them? You obviously cancelled them in your later calculation, but why in the world would you bother to put them there in the first place? Is it some masochistic tendency?

Comment: The initial equation was a simplification of an earlier one in my calculations, I just didn't think while typing the question to remove _Cp_

Comment: The big problem is that when you solved the differential equation for $T_2$ you assumed that $T_1$ (as well as $F$ and $M_2$) to be constant. Yet in your initial conditions and final example, $T_1$ has different values. So your treatment of $T_1$ as being constant was not justified.

Comment: The correct solution for $T_2$ in this case is $$T_2 =re^{-rt}\int T_1\,dt$$ where $r = \frac F{M_2}$. If you do not know $T_1$, then you are going to need a second equation involving it, as there is no farther you can go with the information given.